If "tutear" is addressing as "tu" then what is the equivalent or a close match for "usted"?
It could also mean treating someone formally as opposed to using "tu"
Example use:
No tutees al Jefe. ____ al Jefe. (or something like that)

I don't find the verb ustedear to be in common use. I would say "tratar de usted".
Thus,

No tutees al Jefe, trátale de usted.


I know that, at least in Colombia, people use the term ustedear. Interestingly, I didn’t even realize that ustedear is an actual word listed in the RAE dictionary, as someone mentioned earlier. I always thought we had just made it up. :D

The word (or verb) I think you are looking for is «Vosear» (the opposite of «Tutear» verb):
https://dle.rae.es/vosear#c41xF18
So, in that case, is better "Tratar de usted al jefe" or "Vosear al Jefe". I admit it's a non-common daily word to use, but know that word because one of my past jobs was working as a translator for MS Products, and I struggled my brain ±10 years ago with same question, you here can find the use of «Tuteo / Voseo» in the regional options for the Windows 10 menus

